# Correct way to pass a character array as a pointer from C to assembly to be modified?

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, arm

I have a function in my `main()` C file, which calls a subroutine `getop` from my assembly file.

```
#define MAXOP 20
#define NUMBER '0'

while ((type = getop(s, MAXOP)) != EOF) {
        switch (type) {
        case NUMBER:
            push(atoi(s));
            break;
        default:
            printf("unknown command %c\n", type);
            break;
    }
}
```

`getop` recieves two paramaters, `*s` and `MAXOP`.

`s` is the character array, while `MAXOP` is just an integer.

Since `getop` recieves `s` as a pointer, I thought I could save the address of `s` by doing this in my `getop` subroutine:

```
ldr     x9, [x0]             // Load first argument (*s) into x9
str     x9, [x22]            // Store base address (*s) into register x22
```

So from my knowledge register `x22` now holds the address of `s`. But I'm not sure if that's true.

Throughout my code I input a given character into the character array `s`, and I can see that this works when debugging. If I print out the values at `x22` in gdb, I see that I get the correct ASCII code for the first byte. The way I push this character into the array is by doing

```
str     w11, [x22, w13, SXTW 2]
```

where `w11` is the register holding the character I want, `x22` is the base address as specified before, and `w13` is an offset (should just be `1` intially).

Then the code returns `'0'` to `main()`, so `case NUMBER` gets executed. However, at this point `s` does not seem to equal anything (it should have the correct character in the first index). For example, if I print out the character array or the first item in the array, I don't get any output.

It seems like there's a problem with how I'm modifying the values at `s` and I'm guessing I am not changing the values at the right address?

Comment: `ldr` and `str` operate on memory. If you just want to transfer between registers use a `mov` (but it isn't obvious that you even need to move from `x0`). To write bytes, use `strb`.

Comment: Well I want to change the actual values at `s` in assembly, such that it remains changed when I return to my `main`.

Comment: Yes, that was clear. But your first `ldr`-`str` pair is supposedly just transferring `x0` into `x22` as per the comments and you are doing that wrong. That actually transfers the first 8 bytes from `s` to wherever `x22` happens to be pointing.

Comment: So if I did `mov    x22, x0` instead, then I could change the values at `x22` and then `s` would be changed accordingly when returned to `main`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. But you don't need to even copy to `x22` you can just use `x0` as is.

Comment: Thank you, using `mov` instead of the `ldr`-`str` pair fixed it.